# write on html page dynamically

Tags: javascript

This is the code I am using for posting a line on my html page dynamically, the problem is the page goes empty when i refresh it,i want the line to be written permanently on the page

```
    <html>
    <br><br>post a question <br>
    <br><br><textarea id="t"></textarea><br>
    <br><br><button id='a'>Post</button>
    <div id='updateDiv'></div>

    <script language= "javascript">
    function displayDate()
    {
    var comment = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = comment;
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);
    document.getElementById("t").value = "";
    }

    document.getElementById("a").onclick = displayDate;
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you want to persist the data, you may have to use some kind server technologies like php, java to save the data in the server so that you can retrieve ti later.

Comment: If you want to save it locally for some purpose, you can think of cookie or if you want to support only new browsers you can think of localStorage

Answer (score 3):

When you refresh the page, it makes a new request to the server for the whole page.  Which means it gets a whole new copy of the markup which then executes this script again adding an empty paragraph.  There is no way to change this behavior of browser refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to use a serverside language to store the values or use something like localstorage.

Example using localStorage

```
(function() {

    var outDiv = document.getElementById("updateDiv");

    function displayDate () {
        var comment = document.getElementById("t").value;
        var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
        newParagraph.textContent = comment;
        outDiv.appendChild(newParagraph);
        localStorage.setItem("data", outDiv.innerHTML);
        document.getElementById("t").value = "";
    }

    document.getElementById("a").onclick = displayDate;
    var str = localStorage.getItem("data");
    if (str) {
        outDiv.innerHTML = str;
    }

})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDZPA/)

Just remember that using localstorage means it is only available to that user on that browser. If you want more people to see it, you need to use a serverside solution.